# Multiproject SBT build bad symbolic reference scala-reflect runtime

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-reflect

I've been tasked with rewriting an old ant build script to SBT. As it happens, our suite is built up of 3 modules:

- A Play 2.3 front-end webserver;
- A back-end for retrieving data from various other systems;
- A middle module containing some shared classes for database access and business logic.

Below an excerpt of my Build.scala file can be found:

```
val sharedSettings = Seq(
  organization        := <organization here>,
  version             := "1.2.5",
  scalaVersion        := "2.11.1",
  libraryDependencies ++= libraries,
  unmanagedJars in Compile ++= baseDirectory.value / "lib",
  unmanagedJars in Compile ++= baseDirectory.value / "src",
  unmanagedJars in Compile ++= baseDirectory.value / "test"
)

lazy val middle = project.settings(sharedSettings: _*)
lazy val back = project.settings(sharedSettings: _*).dependsOn(middle)
```

However, when I try to compile the source, I get the following error:

> bad symbolic reference to scala.reflect.runtime encountered in class file 'ValueConverter.class'. Cannot access term runtime in package scala.reflect. The current classpath may be missing a definition for scala.reflect.runtime, or ValueConverter.class may have been compiled against a version that's  incompatible with the one found on the current classpath.

The source code is organized in the following structure:

- back

  - src
  - test
  - lib
- middle

  - src
  - test
  - lib
- front

  - src
  - test
  - lib

Here each lib folder contains some manually maintained libraries (which is why we want to move to sbt).

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: are you declaring scala-reflect as a library dependency?

Comment: Any reason you use Scala 2.11.1 instead of 2.11.7? Where does `ValueConverter` come from - is it one of the manually maintained libraries? Probably it was compiled against an older Scala version like 2.10? The key here is not 'missing scala.reflect.runtime' (as your title suggests), but **bad symbolic reference**

Comment: I've tried to add reflect as a dependency but unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: I've changed the title according to your suggestion. I'm using 2.11.1 because that was the version we were using earlier. I don't want to change too much settings in one go. (I tried changing it to 2.11.7 which didn't help.) The ValueConverter class is indeed part of a library (scallop). The used version was compiled against version 2.11.0. Changing the scala version to 2.11.0 didn't help either. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I gave up on trying to get the compiler to understand the additional libraries. Eventually, I added those dependencies that were available using sbt, to the sbt managed libraries. This apparently works well.